# Links with list of entities are getting rendered for any link instead of proper page in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am relatively new to the Spring boot application. This has been working fine lately until I  introduced a new entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_resource_access")
public class StudentResourceAccess extends implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private StudentResourceAccessPK studentResourceAccessPK;

  @MapsId("studentId")
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Student student;

  @MapsId("userId")
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private User user;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "role")
  private UserRole role;

  }
```

Associated PK class is as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class StudentResourceAccessPK implements Serializable {

  private String studentId;

  private String userId;

  @Column(name = "external_entity_type")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ExternalEntityType externalEntityType;
}
```

Now after making this change, when I am launching my Spring boot application, any link I would like to browse, I am seeing very weird content just like below:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "entity1" : {
      "href" : "https://example.com/entity1{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "entity2" : {
      "href" : "https://example.com/entity2{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    ...
    "studentResourceAccess" : {
      "href" : "https://example.com/studentResourceAccess{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    ..
```

I don't have any idea, why is this coming and how should I fix this? Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I have spring-data-rest in the dependency tree for a long time. This has been working fine. Suddenly with the above change, as I mentioned, it started behaving this way. No idea, why is this happening.

Comment: looks like spring-data-rest would automatically expose an api for your entity repositories, did you maybe accidentally include that dependency somehow..?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Comment: @fladdimir But here I can not see any API in the list, I can see only entities in the list. Can it happen because of messing with any entity?

Comment: @fladdimir Also, spring-data-rest has been on the dependency list for a long time. This has been working fine for so long.  I am not able to figure out, why suddenly I am getting this issue.

Comment: https://tech.asimio.net/2020/04/06/Adding-HAL-Hypermedia-to-Spring-Boot-2-applications-using-Spring-HATEOAS.html